# What does "their" in "their next" refer to?

Tags: the-matrix

In *Matrix* (1999),Trinity answers a ringing public telephone and vanishes just before an
Agent crashes a truck into the booth.

> Brown: We have the name of **their** next target.
>
> Jones: The name is Neo.

What does "their" in "their next" refer to?

Comment: This is not a terrible question. It is interesting that the Agents understand that there is an organization that exists outside of the Matrix. They might have thought that random humans keep dying or something. (Maybe I do not know the movies that well.) Anyway, too many downvotes, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this instance, the Agents are referring to the next target of the Zionese rebels (e.g. **Morpheus, Trinity and the crew of the Nebuchadnezzar**) who are actively looking for *"The One"* (e.g. Neo).

> ***"We [Agents] have [acquired] the name of their [The Zionese Rebels led by Morpheus'] next target[, Neo].***

---

Interestingly, this exchange between the agents went through several re-writes. In the 1996 (first draft), it's quite terse.

> [His jaw sets as he grinds his molars in frustration. AGENT JONES walks up behind him.]
>
> **AGENT SMITH:** *Did you get anything from the room?*
>
> **AGENT JONES:** *Their next target.  The name is Neo.*

In the 1997 redraft it's:

> [His jaw sets as he grinds his molars in frustration. AGENT JONES walks
> up behind him.]
>
> **AGENT JONES:** *Then the informant is real.*
>
> **AGENT SMITH:** *Does that surprise you?  It was inevitable.*
>
> **AGENT JONES:** *He'll be contacting us again.*
>
> **AGENT SMITH:** *Expect it.  Did you get anything from the room?*
>
> **AGENT JONES:** *Their next target.  The name is Neo.*

And in the [Shooting Script](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Matrix-Newmarket-Shooting-Script/dp/1557044902) it's as follows:

> [His jaw sets as he grinds his molars in frustration.
> AGENT JONES and BROWN walk up behind him.]
>
> **AGENT JONES:** *She got out.*
>
> **AGENT SMITH:** *It doesn't matter.*
>
> **AGENT BROWN:** *The informant is real.*
>
> [Agent Smith almost smiles.]
>
> **AGENT SMITH:** *Yes.*
>
> **AGENT JONES:**  *We have the name of their next target.*
>
> **AGENT BROWN:** *The name is Neo.*

Answer (score 2):

Trinity, Morpheus, et al. Neo is the next person they are going to target to free from the Matrix.